# How to add custom category block

Tags: magento2, category, blocks

I'd like to create a new custom category block, that will display it's subcategories. I have created a new file:

**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/subcategories.phtml**

and in my theme's category layout file:

**app/design/frontend/domino/domino1/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml**

I placed the following code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.subcategories" template="Magento_Catalog::category/subcategories.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Am I missing something?